# Deploy and run two applications on one tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I currently have one .war running on tomcat, I wonder if I put another .war in webapp directory, will it work also? if they have different names? I should really try this because webapp currently running is important so I have to check first.

So if I have appX running, and if I put appY in webapp directory will I be able to run two web projects ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Tomcat will unwrap your war file to create a directory by the same name. You should then be able to browse both applciations at the respective context path. For example, localhost:8080/appX and http://localhost:8080/appY.